# Windows 8.1 won't boot after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10728209/

Not sure what happened...  I can see my Windows 8.1 partitions, but the PC will not boot Windows.  I don't have a Windows CD.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you boot Windows ?

Comment: When I choose 'Windows Boot Manager' from GRUB, I get the 'Windows' EFI list which includes Windows Boot Manager and ubuntu.  When I choose Windows Boot Manager from this 2nd list, I get the 1/2/3 message stating File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi is not there.  Can I find this online? I don't have a Windows Install Disc.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem with reruninng boot-repair and after that running `sudo update-grub`

Comment: update not found

Comment: Excuse me i changed it to `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks.  I tried rerunning boot-repair and ran  sudo update-grub  No luck.  I can see my Windows partition from Ubuntu, and found Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi backup in there.  Just don't know how to get the system to boot back into Windows.

Comment: If this is not helping then I don't know what to do

Comment: Did you have any other than the default options selected in boot-repair?

Comment: Neither Boot-Repair nor update-grub can fix a broken Windows boot loader.

Comment: I had deleted a Windows8 entry in EasyBCD, like another user here.  Since there was a 'Windows Boot Manager' still in there, I thought I was fine, until I could not boot into windows.  Looking into repair solutions now.  All of Windows partition is visible - it would be a shame to lose it all.

Comment: I ended up using a boot loader fix: Easy Recovery Essentials for Windows8 (same people that made EasyBCD.  They really need a warning when the user starts cleaning critical boot loaders. Thanks everyone!